# How to declare and use custom configuration file for less compilation with grunt?

Tags: magento2.2.2, less-css, grunt

According to devdocs which is located at

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/tools/using_grunt.html#grunt_config

Now I simply can't understand what it is trying to say.Can anyone explain in brief?

Thanks in advance

**Found the solution.Actually there was an error in theme name.So execution stopped in local-themes.js.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per documentation at below link

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/tools/using_grunt.html#grunt_config

Now as per documentation copy the **themes.js** located at ***dev/tools/grunt/configs*** and rename it to **local-themes.js** as the configuration has been changed in grunt-config.json file which is now.

```
{
    "themes": "dev/tools/grunt/configs/local-themes"
}
```

Put your theme configuration in local-themes.js file and then run grunt commands and it will now work.